# How to create a task switcher (alt + tab) kind of pop up window in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, awt

I have a Pop up that comes up in my application with a list of options but I need to make a window just like windows(Alt + Tab) or linux(Alt + ~) task switcher. I created a JOptionPane which is not exactly the way I want. Is there any other Java feature that can be used  ?

Thanks